# Is there a way to get gradient values from my regression plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I am plotting my regression results using ggplot2 in R. I have my data split into males and females, is there a way to get trend line correlation coefficients for these two groups separately, i.e. one for females and one for males?

I am using the current script below:

```
model <- lm(BMD ~ Sex + Age + PercentDepth + 
              Sex*Age + Sex*PercentDepth + Age*PercentDepth, 
            data = SD_MFC_DATA_LENGTHv6)
summary(model)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(SD_MFC_DATA_LENGTHv6, 
       aes(x = Age,
           y = BMD,
           group = Sex,
           color = Sex,
           shape = Sex)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(fill = Sex)))
```

Example data from SD_MFC_DATA_LENGTHv6:

[Example data pt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOrw1.png)[Example data part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIFsA.png)

Comment: Hi Sammie! On stackoverflow you need to share a reproducible example. Please add the output of `dput(SD_MFC_DATA_LENGTHv5)`. Also, your model and your plot don't show the same thing. In the `lm` model your target is `BMD`, while in the plot is `Tb.Th`. How is the linear model related to the plot?

Comment: Hi Sammie. You have three different predictor variables plus interactions, so your model actually describes two different planes in a three-dimensional space, not two trendlines in a 2D space. This is because there will be a different "trendline" for each sex on age versus BMD for each infintesimal value of PercentDepth. If you leave PercentDepth out of your model, you could plot what you are asking for. If you leave it in, then plotting 2 trendlines just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi Allan, sorry, I was meant to change it so they both are related to BMD. Ah, ok, the three-dimensional space makes sense. Unfortunately, I need to include percentage depth, as that it is very important to the results. I can try to make a reproducible version of my data, there is a lot of data so I could not include it here

Comment: @AllanCameron I've added in some example data, unfortunately, I couldn't format it within the question, so it's added as a link